# xpath getting text in p tag - xpath axes?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="details">
    <p><b>Compatibility:</b> All versions</p>
    <p><b>Category:</b> Entertainment</p>
    <p><b>Updated:</b> Apr 2, 2014</p>
    <p><b>Version:</b> 1.3</p>
    <p><b>Size:</b> 1 MB</p>
    <p><b>Language:</b> English</p>
    <p><b>Artist:</b>Arts101</p>
</div>
```

I need to get the text in the `p` tag, such as:

- Compatibility
- All versions
- Category
- Entertainment

and so on...

Assuming that I already know that Compatibility, Category etc exist, how can I get the corresponding text i.e All versions, Entertainment and so on? i.e. I need some xpath that would search by "Compatibility", and give me "All versions".

I think I would need to use xpath axes, but not sure how..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Get the `b` tag by `text()` and select the following `text` sibling:

```
//b[text()="Compatibility:"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Demo using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

```
$ xmllint input.html --xpath '//b[text()="Compatibility:"]/following-sibling::text()'
All versions
```

Comment: @newdev14 great, consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can test the contents of the `b` element which is inside `p`, and then get the contents of `p`:

```
/div[@class='details']/p[contains(b, 'Compatibility')]/text()
```